# Unable to cast '<T>d__14`1[System.Object] to 'IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable, yield, system.reflection

I'm trying to create generator of **IEnumerable** to set **School.Foundation**,

this is the Type that I'm trying to populate at the moment:

```
public class School
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Foundation;
}
```

this is my generator so far:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetEnumerable <T>(Func<T> f)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            yield return f();
        }
    }
```

So what I'm doing is the following reflection:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<object>> funcMembers;

public static object Generator(String name, Type t)
{
    Func<object> func;
    if (funcMembers.TryGetValue(name, out func))
    {
         if (t.Name.StartsWith("IEnumerable"))
             return GetEnumerable(func);
    }
}
```

I made the following test to check if it was fully functional:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_generator()
    {   
        private Dictionary<string, Func<object>> funcMembers = new Dictionary<string, Func<object>>();

        //adding the Field "Foundation" generator on the dictionary
        funcMembers.Add("Foundation", () => {return 4;}); 

        School s = new School();

        // calling my Generator that should return IEnumerable<int>
        s.Foundation = Generator(
                         "Foundation",
                          typeof(School).GetField("Foundation").

        Assert.IsNotNull(s.Foundation);
    }
```

i have the following error when I'm on line:

```
s.Foundation = Generator(
                     "Foundation",
                      typeof(School).GetField("Foundation").
```

the error is the following:

```
> Unable to cast object of type '<GetEnumerable>d__14`1[System.Object]'
> to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `funcMembers` contain this:

```
funcMembers.Add("Foundation", () => {return 4;});
```

the right-hand-side is an anonymous delegate, parameterless, returning constant `4`. It is implicitely typed as `Func<object>` soit can be added to the dictionary. As all delegates, compiler compiles it as a class, but since it doesn't have name, a special name of "d__14`1[System.Object]" is automatically generated.

Then, it seems that either `Generator` or `GetEnumerable` method return this delegate object directly, instead of invoking it and getting the value of `4` and wrapping it into IEnumerable.

This delegate returned from `Generator` or `GetEnumerable` is then assigned to s.Foundation, which causes this error you noticed (since the anonymous class of the delegate obviously doesn't implement IEnumerable).

I bet you can see all of that simply by stepping with the debugger.For a better view, write it like that:

```
   var tmp = Generator(
                     "Foundation",
                      typeof(School).GetField("Foundation")...
   s.Foundation = tmp;
```

and observe the value in TMP and then, well, diagnose what's up (ie. by stepping into Generator and seeing what happens there) and fix it.

Side note: This is as far as got with these code scraps you pasted. I can't tell you more about your problem, because the code you provided contains severe errors (i.e `Generator` - not all code paths return value), some lines are incomplete (where's the end of `typeof(School).GetField("Foundation").`?) and so on.

In such cases, please try to provide [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which actually compiles.